# How to initialize NSMutableArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

In my app there is huge number of array lists. That's why I have added all arrays in one main array list,  and I have initialized them using a "for" loop.

I am getting error inside the "for" loop: "Fast enumeration variables can't be modified in ARC by default".

```
  NSMutableArray * MainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:NameArray, IdArray, MasterIdNameArray, MasterIdArray, nil];

    for (NSMutableArray * array in MainArray) {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

Comment: Yes.. You need not initialize the array again inside the loop.. Its already been initialised

Comment: so how can we intialized arrays

Comment: Try this....... array = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: no same eror shoiwng

Comment: Please be clear on what you want.. You want to use the arrays which is declared outside and want it to initailise inside the loop right?

Comment: yes ur exactly right

Comment: Since you are asking why this error is appearing : @BalajiKondalrayal has answered it. what's your further requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can not modify the values of array in a fast enumeration, i.e. `for(x in Array)`. The object `x` becomes `constant`, hence it would through a warning.

However you can use `for(int i=0; i<[MainArray count]; i++)` loop to achieve this.

**But, wait:** Why you want to initialize it after adding it to an array. Do it like this:

```
//first create all the arrays that you have,
//NameArray
//IdArray
//MasterIdNameArray
//MasterIdNameArray
//then add them in the MainArray

NSMutableArray *nameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *idArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *masterIdNameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *masterIdNameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [@[nameArray, idArray, masterIdNameArray, masterIdNameArray] mutableCopy];
```

Note: I renamed all the variable for the shake for Naming Conventions in Objective-C.

Comment: clearly tell me with code please i am very new for this technology

Comment: i am not asking how to add all arrays in my main array my meaning is reduce the code lines beacsuee i ahve huge number of arrays that's i want intialize all that arrays using for lopp that's it

Comment: i mean in above u also intialize all for arrays i want to intialized that all array using for loop for code lines reducing purpose

Comment: How will you create/allocate `variableArray`? If you are creating it then why you are not initializing it at same place?

Answer (score 2):

SeanChense is correct. You cannot put an array without initializing it.

```
NSMutableArray * MainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0;i < YOURCOUNTHERE;i++) {
   NSMutableArray * array= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [mainArray addObject:array];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `NameArray` is nil, `MainArray` is nil.
You can do it likes:

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++) {
   [mainArray addObject:[@[] mutableCopy]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my app there is huge number of array lists. That's why I have added all arrays in one main array list, and I have initialized them using a "for" loop.

You appear to be misunderstanding how variables and reference types work. Maybe the following will help:

Your line of code:

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nameArray, idArray, masterIdNameArray, masterIdArray, nil];
```

*copies* the references stored in each of the *variables* `nameArray`, `idArray` etc. and stores those references in a new array.

Somewhere you must declared each of these variables, e.g. something like:

```
NSMutableArray *nameArray;
```

This declares a *variable* `nameArray` which can hold a *reference* to a mutable array, that is a reference of type `NSMutableArray *`. The variable is initialised with the value `nil` - the "no reference" value.

When your first line of code is executed the value in each variable is passed in the method call, *not* the variable itself, so the call is effectively:

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil, nil, nil, nil, nil];
```

and `mainArray` is set to reference a new mutable array with zero elements - as all references *before the first* `nil` in the argument list are used as the initial values in the array.

After `mainArray` has been setup in this way any operation on it has no effect on the values stored in variables `nameArray` *et al.* - there is no connection to those variables. In your loop:

```
for (NSMutableArray *array in mainArray) {
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

The variable `array` is a new variable, which is set in turn to each of the *values* in `mainArray`. The variable `array` **does not** become an alias for each of the variables `nameArray` *et al.* in turn - `mainArray` holds *values* not *variables*.

HTH and you now understand why your code could never do what you intended - that is set the values stored in the variables `nameArray` *et al.*.